# How do I modify a textbox / execute code when a radio button is checked in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I'm working on a web page that was created by a team mate.

There's this button (which leads to a pop-up window date picker) which will automatically fill out several textboxes and labels below it (it works). However, beside one of the text boxes there's a pair of radio buttons, only one can be selected. Upon selection of either one of the radio buttons, the value in the textbox should change.

Currently, it doesn't. Here's the code for the radio buttons.

```
<select name="apply_hrs_wholeday" id="apply_hrs_wholeday" onchange="javascript:UpdateExcesshoursApplicationForm('Apply_hrs_selection');">                        
                    <option value='1' <%=(requestApplicationForm.Apply_hrs_wholeday ? " selected " : "")%>>
                        Whole day
                    </option>
                    <option value='2' <%=(!requestApplicationForm.Apply_hrs_wholeday ? " selected " : "")%>>
                        Half-day
                    </option>
                </select>
```

Now, since it's not my code, I admit I am having trouble reading it. I noticed he did not use asp: something, however, I am reluctant to replace it completely as it will probably mess up other parts of the code. I believe the javascript there was used to prevent the page from reloading or load some variables(?) from the code, but I'm not certain.

I'd like to ask if there's something simple I can do (postback, maybe?), or add to the current code that will allow the detection of a radio button onclick event, and execute some new code.

The Javascript:

```
function UpdateExcesshoursApplicationForm(action, app_id, app_index) {
var senddata;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }



    if(app_id==null)
        app_id=0;

    if(app_index==null)
        app_index=0;


    var PaycodeTypeObj;
    var PaycodeTypeText;
    PaycodeTypeObj=document.getElementById('PaycodeType');
    PaycodeTypeText=PaycodeTypeObj.options[PaycodeTypeObj.selectedIndex].text;


    var workflowactionidObj;     
    var workflowactionidText;
    workflowactionidObj=document.getElementById('workflowactionid');
    workflowactionidText=workflowactionidObj.options[workflowactionidObj.selectedIndex].text;


    senddata=getfrmValues(document.getElementById('frmRequestApplicationForm')) + 
             '&action=' + action + '&PaycodeTypeText=' + PaycodeTypeText + '&workflowactionidText=' + workflowactionidText + '&app_id=' + app_id + '&app_index=' + app_index;                 

    xmlHttp.open('POST',URL.value,false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.send(senddata);

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if(xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            var data = xmlHttp.responseText;
            var start = data.indexOf("pageForm")+10;
            var end = data.indexOf("endPageDivForm")+17;
            document.getElementById("pageForm").innerHTML = data.substring(start,end);
            initializeControls();

            if(action=='Validate') {
                if(document.getElementById("Valid").value=='True') {
                    revealModal(document.getElementById('frmRequestApplicationForm'),'modalEmployeeHrsConfirmation');
                }
            }

            if(action=='Refresh') {
                    revealModal(document.getElementById('frmRequestApplicationForm'),'modalEmployeeHrsSelection');
            }else if(action=='ShowPaycode') {
                    revealModal(document.getElementById('frmRequestApplicationForm'),'modalPaycode');
            }else if(action=='ShowWorkflow') {
                    revealModal(document.getElementById('frmRequestApplicationForm'),'modalWorkflow');
            }else if(action=='ShowEmployee') {
                    revealModal(document.getElementById('frmRequestApplicationForm'),'modalEmployeeInfo');
            }


        } 
   }
```

Comment: Just asking the team mate who wrote this (or any other one) might be the simplest possible solution.

Comment: He's in the hospital. Sorry. :(

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Hope it's nothing serious!

Comment: Dengue, nothing serious, but I'm on my own, until he is fully recovered. I'm studying the code and trying to follow the logic, and it appears rather different from standard ASP - Postback stuff.